# How to setup linux on drive d without removing windows on drive c and other drives

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

I am a starter in Linux. I was having a windows laptop with the hard drive split into 5 drives. Drive C Windows 8.1, Drive D and G empty. Other drives has important data.

I want install Linux on drive D.

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=1496tzm&s=8

how i partition hard disk and install Linux?

Comment: In Linux you only have one drive, but many partitions. Windows confuses "drive" as  a d: drive may be another partition on the same physical drive or another physical drive. In Linux sda is one physical drive and sdb a second physical drive. And sda1 is first partition, sda2 etc for more partitions. For Linux partition must be ext4 which you cannot create from Windows. You either reformat or delete current NTFS.  But as with any change have good backups. http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: First write the question a way that it is clear what is a drive and what is a partition. And it will be quite easy to install.

Comment: What Fred Said. :-)    One of the things I've sometimes found to be helpful to safely do this is to boot the Ubuntu LiveCD, install GPartEd (it isn't there by default), and delete the partition (or format it as ext4) there; then when you start the installer, it's clearer where you want it to go and you're not trying to use that tool (which I don't find to be as friendly as GParted) to do the deed at the same time as the install.